# nebula-test fails to find resources dir in classpath for copyResources

Tags: groovy, gradle, nebula-test

I'm writing integration tests for my first Gradle plugin using nebula-test.

I'm now working on a test that requires copying one or more files from my "resources" into the temp project directory.  The "copyResources()" call is failing because it says the "from" directory is not in the classpath.

Specifically, it fails with this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find classpath resource: src/integTest/resources
at nebula.test.IntegrationSpec.copyResources(IntegrationSpec.groovy:189)
at com.att.opnfv.yang.gradle.YangPluginIntegSpec.process Yang module with simple type reference and imported file for type(YangPluginIntegSpec.groovy:227)
```

Here's the relevant pieces of my "build.gradle" file:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'java-gradle-plugin'
    apply plugin: 'maven'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9"
        compile gradleApi()
        compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"

        testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3") {
            exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
        }
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7

    group = 'com.att.opnfv.yang'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    tasks.withType(Test) {
            testLogging {
                    exceptionFormat "full"
            }
    }

    sourceSets {
        integTest {
            groovy.srcDir file("src/integTest/groovy")
            resources.srcDir file("src/integTest/resources")
            runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath // I thought this would do it
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        integTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
        integTestCompile configurations.testCompile
        integTestCompile sourceSets.test.output
        integTestRuntime configurations.testRuntime

        testCompile( 'com.netflix.nebula:nebula-test:2.2.1' ) {
            exclude module: 'groovy-all'
        }
    }

    task integTest(type: Test) {
        testClassesDir  = sourceSets.integTest.output.classesDir
        classpath     = sourceSets.integTest.runtimeClasspath
        outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    }

    check.dependsOn -= integTest
```

And here's my Spec method that has the "copyResources()" call:

```
def 'process Yang module with simple type reference and imported file for type'() {
    when:
    directory("src/main/yang")
    File yangFile = createFile("src/main/yang/base.yang")
    yangFile << '''
    module base {
        namespace "base";
        prefix base;

        import ietf-inet-types {prefix inet; revision-date "2010-09-24";}

        grouping "group" {
            leaf ip-base {
                type inet:ip-version;
            }
        }
    }
    '''.stripIndent()

    directory("yangImports")

    copyResources("src/integTest/resources", "yangImports") // line 227

    buildFile << applyPlugin(YangPlugin)
    buildFile << """
        configurations {
            yangImports
        }
        dependencies {
            yangImports fileTree(dir: "yangImports", include: "*.yang")
        }
        yang {
            yangFilesConfiguration "yangImports"
            inspectDependencies     true
            yangFilesRootDir        'src/main/yang'
            generator {
                generatorClassName  = 'com.att.opnfv.yang.generator.MockCodeGenerator'
                outputDir           = 'build/gen'
            }
        }
    """.stripIndent()

    ExecutionResult result = runTasksWithFailure('build')

    then:
    !result.wasUpToDate("yangGenerate")
    result.standardError.contains("Imported module ietf-inet-types not found")
}
```

What am I missing?

**Update**:

I was confused about the relationship between the configuration classpath and the path referenced in "copyResources".  I created "src/integTest/resources/yang", copied the one file into that new folder, then changed the reference to:

```
copyResources("yang", "yangImports")
```

and that worked, or at least it got past that problem just so I could hit my next hurdle, but that's not a Gradle/nebula-test problem.

Comment: Oh, duh. New record on finding solution soonest after writing SO posting. My "copyResources" has to reference a folder INSIDE "src/integTest/resources", not "src/integTest/resources" itself.  I created another folder there called "yang", moved the file I wanted to copy into there, then changed the path to "yang", and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was referencing "src/integTest/resources" in the "copyResources" call.  That folder is already in the classpath.  What I needed to reference was the folder INSIDE of "src/integTest/resources".  Once I did that, it worked fine.